# MCP3008 Adafruit code not work with Python 3?

Tags: python, pi-3, version-control

So I am working on a project turning a Raspberry Pi and an MCP3008 chip into a voltage meter.  A bunch of the examples I was working off of used the code for the chip put out my Adafruit that can be found on [their github](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_MCP3008).  A problem I noticed is that when running my Python code through Python 3 as opposed to Python 2, I get the error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'RPi.SPI'
```

This is an error coming from the package of Adafruit code for `import Adafruit_MCP3008`

Does anyone have a work around or is this something I'll have to live with?  Most of the other code I made for this project runs on Python 3 so I am not sure if I am going to have version errors (I'm using PySerial 3.3 for a different part of the project, as well as I made the interface to work with Python3 tkinter)

Comment: Why not use the GPIOZero code from yesterday?

Comment: @SteveRobillard Simply put, the GPIOZero code from yesterday wasn't giving me proper values.  GPIOZero was giving me a floating point number between 0.0 and 1.0, where as I was looking for the bit value from the chip, which would be a number between 0 and 1023.  The Adafruit Code was code that let me get the data I was looking for.  If I have to go back to the GPIOZero code I will, but I want to see if this is a fixable issue first.

Comment: to convert the GPIOZero value to 0-1023 just multiply it time 1023. So if you get .8 from GPIOZero do this 0.8 * 1023 which gives 818.4000000000001 if you need an integer you can do round(0.8 * 1023).

Comment: I also gave you the code needed to turn the GPIOZero value into a voltage.